# Is removing outliers in time series data a valid procedure?

Tags: time-series, outliers

I am currently working on a project where i want to do time series forecasting on energy consumption forecasting of single family households. I am struggling on how to deal with spikes occuring in the data. I have a dataset with little less than 1000 timestamps.

I have tried to simply smooth the spikes using three-sigma rule. For every energy consumption outside of three-sigma intervall i replaced the value with mean+3*sigma. After this procedure, there were still significant spikes.

The idea was to use the residuals of the time series to detect outliers determined by a specific threshold or in other words, datapoints which are different from the majority according to the residuals.

The following plot is showing the power demand with the outliers detected: [image: energy consumption raw]

After removing the outliers the plot looks like this:
[image: energy consumption cleaned]

There are still some spikes in the dataset but the suddenly appearing spikes are reduced.

I am questioning myself if this whole procedure with the removing of spikes is valid or if this will distort the whole model performance. The thing is, that theoretically, there are outliers in the dataset. But from a practical point of view, these are legit outliers. These spikes occur when there is significant change in weather conditions, for example the temperature has declined from 5°C to -10°C in one day.

If i am removing all of these spikes, the model will not generalize well to new data, right? I would assume that the model is performing well on the given dataset but isn't generalizing well.

But if i keep these spikes, the spikes will affect some model performance, since some models like for e.g., neural networks are sensitive to outliers. Can someone tell me if the way of thinking about this is right, or do i have to overseen something? I don't really know how to proceed now.

Thank you in advance.

What i have done is to keep these spikes. unfortunately performance of different models weren't that great.